# One to one/ one to many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-many, one-to-one

I have a Transaction model that has a one to one relationship with Service model, and then the Service model has many ServiceAddons.

```
public class Transaction 
{
   public int TransactionId {get;set;}
   public string Username {get;set;}
   public Service OccasionService {get;set;}
}

public class Service 
{  
   [Key]
   public int TransactionId {get;set;}
   public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
   public virtual IList<ServiceAddon> ServiceAddons { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceAddon
{
    public int ServiceAddonId { get; set; }
    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public int AddonId { get; set; }
    public decimal AddonPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual Addon Addon { get; set; }
}
```

Now the package manager console is telling me that the OccasionServiceId does not exist in ServiceAddon so I changed TransactionId for it, the program compiled but now it says Invalid column OccasionServiceId. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify `ForeignKey`s, try something like this. I've added comments for bits that are unclear.

```
public class Transaction 
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionId {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}

    // Whatever the column is
    public int OccasionServiceId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("OccasionServiceId")] // What on Transaction points to Service's Key
    public Service OccasionService {get;set;}
}

public class Service 
{  
    // Ideally this would be called ServiceId instead?
    [Key]
    public int TransactionId {get;set;}

    // If this uses TransactionId then are you sure you don't need a Key that is ServiceId
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TransactionId")] // What on ServiceAddon points at Service's Key
    public virtual ICollection<ServiceAddon> ServiceAddons { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceAddon
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceAddonId { get; set; }

    // Don't you need a ServiceId here?

    public int TransactionId { get; set; }
    public int AddonId { get; set; }
    public decimal AddonPrice { get; set; }
    public virtual Addon Addon { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what my models would look like if I made it:

```
public class Transaction 
{
    [Key]
    public int TransactionId {get;set;}
    public string Username {get;set;}
    public int ServiceId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ServiceId")]
    public Service Service {get;set;}
}

public class Service 
{  
    [Key]
    public int ServiceId {get;set;}
    public int TransactionId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("TransactionId")
    public Transaction Transaction { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TransactionId")] // What on ServiceAddon points at Service's Key
    public virtual ICollection<ServiceAddon> ServiceAddons { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceAddon
{
    [Key]
    public int ServiceAddonId { get; set; }
    public int ServiceId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("ServiceId")]
    public Service Service {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and package manager said that it's unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types Service and Transaction?

Comment: I think that may be because of your Service.TransactionId which seems to be both a foreign key and a primary key? See my second piece of code.

Comment: It should be something like: `Transaction.TransactionId 1 <-> 1 Service.TransactionId` and `Service.ServiceId 1 <-> * ServiceAddon.ServiceId` I modified the answer a little with `ServiceAddon`. Good luck! Off to bed :P

Comment: Actually, I used your second code. I got it to work now after deleting the database then running it again. now it tells me that ServiceAddons_Service_TransactionId has an unresolved reference?

Comment: You are right I need that Service Id. That's what I wanted to do, I don't know now why I placed TransactionId in there. Thanks